# django ugettext msguniq: too many errors, aborting

Tags: django, translation, gettext

I was working with ugettext for translation and it was ok , but i dont know what has happened that when i write `django-admin makemessages` on command, it shows this lots of errors:

```
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
 C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite       \locale\d
 jango.pot:25:3: syntax error 
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:25: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:25: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:25: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:25: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:42:3: syntax error
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:42: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:42: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:55:3: syntax error
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:55: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:55: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:60:3: syntax error
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:60: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:60: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:60: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:60: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:65:3: syntax error
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:65: keyword "models" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:65: keyword "py" unknown
C:\Users\pouyasystem\Desktop\Project\BallBearingProject\BallbearingSite\locale\d
jango.pot:70:3: syntax error
msguniq: too many errors, aborting
```

And I double checked these lines in settings :

```
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

)
```

when `django-admin makemessages` command is executing a django.pot file appears in "fa" folder (the folder under locale and up to the Lc_MESSAGES) but after errrors this file disappears and i wonder why it try to make .POT file in fa folder and not in Lc_MESSAGES beside django.po and django.mo ?

when i manually add codes to django.po , like :

```
#: .\models.py:29
msgid "car"
msgstr "نوع خودرو"
```

and execute the django-admin compilemessages command, the translate works but makemessages is not working

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder inside of your app and name it `locale`, then create another folder inside of `locale` and name it `fa` for PERSIAN language.

After it your project structure must be same as the bellow:

```
- your_project
- your_app
  - locale
    - fa
manage.py
...
```

Now use `cd` command and go to the `your_app` directory, then use `django-admin makemessages`

After it your project structure must be same as the bellow:

```
- your_project
- your_app
  - locale
    - fa
      - LC_MESSAGES
          django.po
manage.py
...
```

Comment: I have already had this path in the order you said in my project but it doesnt work. it was working properly before but i dont know what had happened that it stopped working !

Comment: Did you find out what was happening? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: No i dont , i added the translations manually in django.po (instead of unsing makemessage) and then execute the compile message .

Answer (score 0):

hi there you should add

'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # new

in middleware after

```
SessionMiddleware
```